# Why is the use of "color" considered an error?

Tags: python-3.x, manim

I have been running a manim code, and it specifies: "TypeError: Mobject.**getattr**..getter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'"

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
from manim import *
class Function(Scene): 
    def construct(self): 
        ax=Axes(x_range=[-5,5,0.5], y_range=[-3,3,0.5], 
                x_axis_config={"numbers_to_include": np.arange(-5,5,1)}, 
                y_axis_config={"numbers_to_include": [1]})
        #ax_labels=ax.get_axis_labels(x_label="Time (t)", y_label=Tex(r"y=sin(x)"))
        ax_labels=ax.get_axis_labels()

        sin_graph=ax.get_graph(lambda x: np.sin(2*x), color=BLUE)
        cos_graph = ax.get_graph(lambda x: np.cos(2*x), color=RED_B)
        sin_label=ax.get_graph_label(sin_graph, label="\\sin(x)", 
                                     x_val=-4.5, direction=UP*4)
        cos_label=ax.get_graph_label(cos_graph, label="\\cos(x)", 
                                     x_val=4.5, direction=DOWN*2)
        ax_group=VGroup(ax, ax_labels)
        #labels=VGroup(sin_label, cos_label)
        self.play(Create(ax_group), run_time=6)
        self.wait()
        self.play(Write(sin_label))
        self.play(Create(sin_graph), run_time=2)
        self.wait()
        self.play(Create(cos_graph), run_time=2)
        self.play(Write(cos_label))
        self.wait()
```

I was expecting an animation of a sin graph, but it didn't work as specified above.

Comment: The error message means that `ax.get_graph` doesn't have a `color` parameter. Did you check the documentation correctly?

Comment: I did not read the whole documentation, but I saw an abundance of codes using it, therefore I assumed it was fine. However, the problem was with the `get_graph` itself, since the new manim version runs `.plot()`, or at least that's what I resorted to. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The error message from `get_graph` is unfortunately somewhat unhelpful. Practically, `get_graph` has been renamed to `plot` a while ago. See the docuementation: https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.graphing.coordinate_systems.CoordinateSystem.html?highlight=plot#manim.mobject.graphing.coordinate_systems.CoordinateSystem.plot

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! I reviewed the problem, and it apparently was with the `get_graph` itself, since it is an older version of `.plot()`. The code worked as soon as I changed it.